# Unable to show full image in a View Controller background

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I am adding a background image in all of my view controllers but was unable to show full image only the top left portion is visible in the output, the code i am using is this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Bg6.png")!)
```

I am Putting this code in all my view controller's `ViewDidLoad()` function

Comment: better way is to use a ImageView and then set the image to it. Problem with `UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Bg6.png")!)` is if image is smaller than the screen size then it will repeat the image on Whole screen.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary the image size is 1600*1200

Comment: @kmithi exactly that happened to me thats why i used a larger size image but now I face this problem..!!  And I was not willing to put an imageview beside instead i was searching for a code to put background image..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use with `CGImage` of view

```
self.view.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"background.png").CGImage
```

Comment: Welcome anytime @IrshadQureshi

Answer (score 1):

I recommended you to do it this way:

Create `UIImageView` then add image in `UIImageView`.

```
let imageName = "night_sky_custom_background_by_rhuni-d5orpob.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.height, height: self.view.bounds.size.height)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't worked properly..!! The background Image is showing correctly but everything else is gone or not visible..!!

Comment: i thinks its behind it. you can add Imageview behind everything